# how to swap the visibility of applications using c#

Tags: c#

i have a parent form, it will have two tabs calling the two child forms respectively.
I did this usind MDI.

For instance, say i have two tabs named "Calculator" and "Notepad". I mean to say that
the name of tabs are the process names running in windows.

The behavior of my parent form is like, a full screen and the user is restricted to use windows task bar.

Now, when the user clicks "calculator" tab, i shud bring the application on top of my parent window. Then if the user clicks "Notepad", then i want to bring the notepad front and rest all the applications shud be behind the parent form. To be more clear, only one application shud be viewable on clicking of the respective tabs with process name.

It sounds tedious !!!

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the TabIndexChanged event of the TabControl and determine which tab page is now currently active. Based on the active tab page you then use a ProcessInfo instance to load the applcition you want to run:

Here's code to get you going:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = null;

        if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
        {
            psi = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
        }
        else if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == tabPage2)
        {
            psi = new ProcessStartInfo("calc.exe");
        }

        if (psi != null)
        {
            psi.ErrorDialog = true;
            psi.ErrorDialogParentHandle = Handle;
            Process.Start(psi);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if the process is already started ???
If i want to check whether the process is already running and if so just show the application. Can ?

Answer (score 0):

From a Google search, it seems you can use P/Invoke to minimize/maximize the applications programmatically. It could be a start.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9bde4870-1599-4958-9ab4-902fa98ba53a